# Is this integral containing $\min(\cdot)$ and $\max(\cdot)$ solvable?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here goes... Original integral is from this post: [Probability of $A+C>B+D$ for $A\sim U(x,1)$, $B\sim U(y,1)$, and $C,D\sim U(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652142/probability-of-acbd-for-a-sim-ux-1-b-sim-uy-1-and-c-d-sim-u0-1/4652168#4652168)

$$\int_y^uf_{V}(v)dv=\int_y^u\frac{\min(1,v)-\max(y,v-1))}{1-y}dv$$

I tried to separate the integral from $y$ to $1$, $1$ to $y+1$, $y+1$ to $u$, but I didn't get anything good :
$$\begin{split}
\int_{y}^{u}f_{V}(v)dv&=\int_{y}^{1}\frac{v-y}{1-y}dv+\int_{1}^{y+1}\frac{1-y}{1-y}dv+\int_{y+1}^{u}\frac{2-v}{1-y}dv\\
&=\frac{1-y}{2}+y+\frac{(-y+u-1)(y+u+3)}{2y-2}
\end{split}$$

Also, $0 < y < 1$ and $y < v < u$.

However, this was not the expected result. Am I doing this correctly?

Edit: Second try, I assume this is not legit (because $v$ is used as a bound and as the variable of integration)?
$$\int_{y}^{u}f_{V}(v)dv=\int_{y}^{v+1}\frac{1-y}{1-y}dv+\int_{v+1}^{u}\frac{2-v}{1-y}dv$$

Comment: Separating the integral should work if done thoroughly. Alternatively, you could try to use the explicit formulas for minimum and maximum:
$$\min(a,b) = \frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$$ and $$\max(a,b) = \frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$$

Comment: Is what I did in my original post legit (I tried separating the integral)? It's not giving me right result sadly.

Comment: By $\min(1-v)$, do you mean $\min(1-v, 0)$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I mean min(1,v), just fixed it.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Yes thanks, just added link to original post.

Answer (score 1):

While you might need a mathematical proof of the result, it doesn't hurt to obtain the answer by other means.

Using *Mathematica* one can define the function with relevant assumptions (a set of assumptions for `Integrate` and the same for `FullSimplify`:

```
fv[u_, y_] := FullSimplify[Integrate[Min[1, v] - Max[y, v - 1]/(1 - y), {v, y, u},
   Assumptions -> 0 < y < 1 && y < u < 2], Assumptions -> 0 < y < 1 && y < u < 2]

fv[u, y]
```

[image: fv(u,v)]

As an example:

```
u0 = 1.2
y0 = 0.34
fv[u0, y0]
(* 0.19917 *)
```

And a check with numerical integration:

```
NIntegrate[Min[1, v] - Max[y0, v - 1]/(1 - y0), {v, y0, u0}]
(* 0.19917 *)
```